# DM Python template - how do you add ssh access to GCE instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

I'm able to create basic instances using Deployment Manager Python templates but how do you enable ssh access? Using properties/metadata fields? Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not able to SSH into the machine after creating the instances, you might need to add a firewall rule to allow connections on port 22. Something like the below will work.

```
def GenerateConfig(context):


"""Creates the firewall with environment variables."""

  resources = [{
      'name': context.env['name'],
      'type': 'compute.v1.firewall',
      'properties': {
          'network': '$(ref.' + context.properties['network'] + '.selfLink)',
          'sourceRanges': ['0.0.0.0/0'],
          'allowed': [{
              'IPProtocol': 'TCP',
              'ports': [22]
          }]
      }
  }]
  return {'resources': resources}
```

Reference: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/step_by_step_guide/step7_use_environment_variables/python/firewall-template.py